# Checking textbox if it's empty in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I wrote a simple html file with a textbox and submit button, and it generates and document.write's a response dependant on what you submit.  I want to have it generate a response saying to enter content if the box is empty.  The textbox's id is chatinput, so I have the following the code in the beginning

```
    var chatinput_box=document.getElementById('chatinput');
    var chatinput=chatinput_box.value;
```

Then a have a conditional, although I can't get it to work correctly; I've tried

```
    if(chatinput==""){}
    if(chatinput.length=0){}
    if(chatinput=null){}
```

and others but none have worked correctly.  Does anyone have another idea?

Comment: These won't work because you use the assignment operator: `if(chatinput.length=0){}` and `if(chatinput=null){}`

Comment: The first one should work. What's your HTML?

Comment: Since an empty string is falsy even `if(chatinput)` should work. Can you show some of your markup? Because there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code... (except the assignment operator as mentioned above)

Comment: Show the HTML for #chatinput

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be this:

```
var chatinput = document.getElementById("chatinput").value;
if (chatinput == "" || chatinput.length == 0 || chatinput == null)
{
    // Invalid... Box is empty
}
```

Or shorthanded:

```
if (!document.getElementById("chatinput").value)
{
    // Invalid... Box is empty
}
```

The `=` assigns a value whereas `==` checks whether the values are equal.

Comment: you should really use strict comparison operators if you are trying to teach the difference between comparison and assignment operators. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript

Comment: This could really be simplified to `if(chatinput)`, it would even be recommendable imho.

Comment: @Houssni And good you noticed to use interpolation for the correct logic ^^

Comment: I like the shorthanded version but is there any drawbacks?

Is it really the same as the first?

Comment: @Crismogram Empty values are always falsely evaluated, so you can use the shorthand version without problems.

Answer (score 3):

Just offering an alternative, not trying to steal thunder ...

Create an `isEmpty` function to reuse on a variety of items.

```
function isEmpty(val){
    return ((val !== '') && (val !== undefined) && (val.length > 0) && (val !== null));
}
```

Then you can apply it to whatever element you want:

```
if(!isEmpty(chatinput)){
    // hooray its got a value!
}
```

Not exactly original, its the concept stolen from PHP, but it comes in handy a lot.

Comment: I like this since it's a reusable, simple function.

Comment: I didn't think of that, that's a great idea.  It would help make code much shorter and more memorable in the future too.

Comment: Yup, exactly. For stuff like this, reusability is king! :D

Comment: This is overhead imo, a default text input value is falsy when it's an empty string, all these chained tests result in exactly the same as when just boolean testing against `val` directly.

Comment: @Simon - the values `undefined` and `null` are defined as legitimate values you can assign to a variable, so your logic would not work for items with those values. the OP clearly states he wanted to test for `null`.

Comment: What does one have to do with the other? Sure you can write `var myVar = undefined || null;` but `if(myVar)` would still be `false`... The test just has to make sure the value is truthy, which is correct for everything other than exactly `undefined`, `null`, `''` or `length 0`. Maybe I missed that, but the OP just wanted to make sure that the value is no empty not that it's not null (which would be covered with simple boolean testing anyway).

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct, I did a little reading ... thats because just checking the variable uses non-strict comparison (`undefined == 'undefined'`), therefore it has length and returns true). good to know, although you should realize that making the exact same comment in three areas without providing an answer yourself really makes u look like a dick. just for future notice.